# "Convergence of A 'with' B" versus "convergence of A 'and' B"

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, phrase-choice

If I want to say "convergence of line A, line B (say outer boundaries) and some other lines (say internal skeleton)" which of the following phrases should I use?

> Convergence of outer boundaries *with* internal skeleton

> Convergence of outer boundaries *and* internal skeleton

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This case is fuzzy to me too, so I decided to search [COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) to see what other people say.

Here's what I found:

```
    "convergence of * and"          130 results
    "convergence of * with"         10 results
```

Based on this, it looks like ***and*** is more popular, but ***with*** is also acceptable.  My intuition is that there is no significant difference in meaning; I looked through some of the results trying to find a pattern, but as far as I can tell they're interchangeable.

It seems to me that both ***and*** and ***with*** are okay, but the usual choice is ***and***.